# Basic creation set in c++

Tags: c++

I have tried to realize set by basic metods via struct.
This is my variant:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

struct Set<T> {
    int n;
    T[n] elements;
}

int main(){
    struct Set microSet;
    int oneElm, length;
    cin>>length;
    microSet.n=length;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        cin>>oneElm;
        microSet.elements[i]=oneElm;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) 
        cout << microSet.elements[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Compilator shows me an error related with sruct.
What've I done wrong?

Comment: What does the actual error text say?  Do note that a struct/class body must end with a `;`.

Comment: You should read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: If this is not a learning exercise, just use `std::set<T>`.

Comment: Something to read: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: It looks like you're attempting a fusion of C++, Java, and C based on guesswork. Get yourself a good book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is illegal (and wrong in many places, so take a few days to read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) then look at some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website). You can't declare a variable length array as a member of a `struct` or `class` (and even if you could, you have the wrong syntax; some compilers support them as an *extension*, and C99 -but no C++ dialect- has [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)).

You'll better use existing standard C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). If you can't use them, you need pointers (and you should prefer [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)).

Even if you have some compiler accepting [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s as an extension, you probably need to [dynamically *allocate*](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) a memory zone for them.

I strongly recommend learning to use containers.

Don't forget to enable all warnings & debug info when compiling. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Use the debugger (`gdb`) and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).